# Coded UI Test Method Runs only when VS is launched as administrator

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm launching Windows application which require admin rights via ProcessStartInfo.
`ProcessStartInfo app= new ProcessStartInfo(Path.exe);
                app.UseShellExecute = true;
                app.Verb = "runas"; 
MainWindow= ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(app);`

Launch is working perfectly but controls are not recognized until I run VS as Administrator. How do i run the testmethod successfully without launching VS as Admin?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign Visual Studio safety from your Windows settings.

1. Right click "Visual Studio" and select "Open file location
2. Right Click "Visual Studio" and select "Properties"
3. Click "Advanced" and check "Run as administrator"